# Is there a way to make a bitbucket pipeline step wait until some condition

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline step that looks something like the following:

```yaml
- docker run [...]
- sleep 5
- ./bin/main
```

However, sometimes the docker container takes a little bit longer to get going causes main to fail. I could increase the time in the sleep statement, but there is no guarantee it would be enough, and excessively long times would use up build minutes needlessly. Is there anything like `wait until {ping localhost:4444}` that I could use to replace that sleep statement?

Comment: Like, a sleep until ready, else fail if not ready after X second

Comment: @JJRohrer have provided an option below, is this what you are after ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this, add a while statement to curl for localhost:4444, so that it only proceeds to the next step when the curl is successful or will exit after 60s with a timeout exit code (28):

```yaml
- docker run [...]
- while ! curl -s -o --connect-timeout 60 /dev/null localhost:4444; do echo Waiting for Container; sleep 1; done
- ./bin/main
```